# javascript map two nested arrays and modify the existing by lookups

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

I have a `kids` object that looks like the following:

```
const kids = {
    name: 'john',
    extra: {
        city: 'London',
        hobbies: [
            {
                id: 'football',
                team: 'ABC',
            },
            {
                id: 'basketball',
                team: 'DEF',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

and i have the following object that contains all sports and extra info for each.

```
const sports = [
    {
        name: 'volleyball',
        coach: 'tom',
    },
    {
        name: 'waterpolo',
        coach: 'jack',
    },
    {
        name: 'swimming',
        coach: 'kate',
    },
    {
        name: 'football',
        coach: 'sara',
    },
];
```

I want to get the list of all `id`s in the hobbies array and go through each of the sports items in the sports array, and found, add an extra field to that object `available` and give a value of `true`, so the result will look like:

```
const result = [
    {
        name: 'volleyball',
        coach: 'tom',
    },
    {
        name: 'waterpolo',
        coach: 'jack',
    },
    {
        name: 'swimming',
        coach: 'kate',
    },
    {
        name: 'football',
        coach: 'sara',
        available: true
    },
];
```

by the way, here is my attempt:

```
const result = kids.extra.hobbies.map(a => a.id);
for (var key in sports) {
    console.log(sports[key].name);
    const foundIndex = result.indexOf(sports[key].name);
    if ( foundIndex > -1) {
      sports[key].available = true;
    }
}
console.log(sports)
```

but this is too long... i am looking one liner looking code and robust logic.

Comment: Just a sidenote, why are these arrays? Why not use objects, if the ids are unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done many ways; however, an easy was is to divide the problem into two steps:

We can first flatten the kid's hobbies into an array by using the `Array.map()` function:

```
const hobbies = kids.extra.hobbies.map(hobby => hobby.id);
```

Then, we can iterate through the sports array and add an `active` property to any object which is present in the new `hobbies` array:

```
const result = sports.map(sport => {
  if (hobbies.indexOf(sport.name) !== -1) {
    sport.available = true;
  }

  return sport;
})
```

---

**Complete Solution**

```js
const kids = {
  name: 'john',
  extra: {
    city: 'London',
    hobbies: [{
        id: 'football',
        team: 'ABC',
      },
      {
        id: 'basketball',
        team: 'DEF',
      },
    ],
  },
};

const sports = [{
    name: 'volleyball',
    coach: 'tom',
  },
  {
    name: 'waterpolo',
    coach: 'jack',
  },
  {
    name: 'swimming',
    coach: 'kate',
  },
  {
    name: 'football',
    coach: 'sara',
  },
];

const hobbies = kids.extra.hobbies.map(hobby => hobby.id);


const result = sports.map(sport => {
  if (hobbies.indexOf(sport.name) !== -1) {
    sport.available = true;
  }

  return sport;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would change my data structures to objects. Any time you have a list of things with unique ids, objects will make your life much easier than arrays. With that in mind, if you must use arrays, you could do the following:

```
const hobbies = kids.extra.hobbies
sports.forEach(s => s.available = hobbies.some(h => h.id === s.name))
```

Note that this mutates the original sports object (change to map for new), and also adds `false/true` instead of just true.

Answer (score 1):

Build an array of the found sports first, then `map` while checking to see if the sports object's name is in it:

```js
const kids = {name:'john',extra:{city:'London',hobbies:[{id:'football',team:'ABC',},{id:'basketball',team:'DEF',},],},}
const sports = [{name:'volleyball',coach:'tom',},{name:'waterpolo',coach:'jack',},{name:'swimming',coach:'kate',},{name:'football',coach:'sara',},];
const sportsInHobbies = kids.extra.hobbies.map(({ id }) => id);
const result = sports.map((sportObj) => {
  const available = sportsInHobbies.includes(sportObj.name);
  return available ? {...sportObj, available } : { ...sportObj };
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I love how you commented on another answer above about iterating over both sets, when yours does exactly the same.